# Show Calendar Dates Horizontally No Library Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to display the calendar in my app like this image here [image: horizontal calendar] but don't know how to go about it. I have checked libraries on github and android-arsenal but can't find anything close to this without meddling with their source code. Any help will be nice.
Thanks.

Comment: Check this library out https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar. And please, googled.

Comment: I have seen that one, but the height is too much for my use case. I have tried editing the source but not clear to me